# adding existing matlab files (*.m) to inbuilt version control of matlab

Tags: matlab, version-control

Can anybody tell me how to add existing matlab files (*.m) to inbuilt version control of matlab 2014b? 
As per given in the link http://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/add-a-project-to-source-control.html#bt7ggid-1, I have tried by right clicking the white space in current working directory but couldn't found the option 'Add project to source control' option under 'Source Control'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That link is for Simulink 2014b, the relevant link for MATLAB 2014b is http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/source-control.html.

In the MATLAB 2014b filebrowser you should have Source Control in the right-click context menu. From there you can set the SVN/Git Repository path (Manage Files) and once set up add files by right-clicking on the file, Source Control -> Add to SVN or Source Control -> Add to Git.